# How to compare strings inside a text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file-io, filestream

I'm learning to read text files and `Streamreader` is the only class I know until now for that purpose.
Until now I've seen this class lets me read the entire file(`.ReadToEnd`), line by line(`.ReadLine`) or character by character(`.Read`).

However I can't figure how to read substrings delimited by `,` and solve this:

( Following 4 lines are the content of textfile.txt)

```
COLUMN1,MAIL1,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,MAIL2
".","user@DOMAIN.EDU.PE","1","2013-05-08 00:00:00","0","user@DOMAIN.EDU.PE"
".","id@DOMAIN1.COM.PE","1","2013-05-08 00:00:00","0","HADSA7@DOMAIN1.COM.PE"
".","myid@DOMAIN2.COM.PE","1","2013-05-08 00:00:00","0","4671@DOMAIN2.COM.PE"
```

If the first email address is equal to the second, do:

```
Numberofmatched=Numberofmatched+1
```

If not

```
Numberofunmatched=Numberofunmatched+1
```

Take in consideration domain name can change and email addresses have variable lenght.

Any help?

Comment: The delimiter is comma not ".

Comment: You might find the [TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) useful.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method to read a text-file. You can use the [`System.IO.File` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example `File.ReadLines`/`File.ReadAllLines` or `File.ReadAllText`.

Use `String.Split` to get a `String()`, one string for each column. Since the delimiter seems to be `,`instead of `"` use [`String.Split(","c)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can use following LINQ query which can increase readability:

```
Dim allLines = File.ReadAllLines("Path")
Dim data = From line In allLines.Skip(1) ' skip the header-line
           Where Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)
           Let fields = line.Split(","c)
           Where fields.Length = 6
           Select fields

Dim Numberofmatched As Int32 = data.Count(Function(fields) fields(1) = fields(5))
Dim Numberofunmatched As Int32 = data.Count(Function(fields) fields(1) <> fields(5))
```

Note that you should use an available CSV-parser instead of reinventing the wheel since they support   quoting characters and a lot of other things. One recommendable in the Visual-Basic namespace is the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.